# What is this strange diamond logo on my Stack Exchange cap?

Tags: support, logo, swag

Today, I received some swag (thanks!). One of the items was a cap, and I was puzzled by the logo on it. I've never seen it before, but it's related to the Stack Exchange logo as it seems to have the same colors. What is it, and is it used in other places?

[image]

<sub>(click to enlarge)</sub>

The logo is now also featured on the [Winter Bash 2017](https://winterbash2017.stackexchange.com/) secret hat 'Ooh, Shiny!'

[image]

which was based on a Winter Bash 2013 secret hat which was awarded for the user being a ♦ moderator.

Comment: A mod diamond colored as the logo perhaps?

Comment: @Kendra I think so. I had an 'aha' moment while posting this question.

Comment: Is that a lighting thing or is your hat really more blue-grey? Mine is more navy.

Comment: @Catija that's the lighting, mine is navy as well.

Comment: .... Clearly someone did not do your moderator briefing properly. They should be suitably flogged with a wet noodle....

Comment: @JourneymanGeek: a diamond-profile wet noodle.

Comment: PS (re: your edit) this hat was originally featured in Winter Bash 2013. It was a secret hat awarded for being a moderator on the site (didn't go over well).

Comment: @animuson thanks, I didn't know that. It wasn't my edit BTW (it's fun, but not directly helpful to answer the question), but I've added your information to the question.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Congrats you've been given a mod hat. And that logo is the diamond. It's a mod-only hat for election winners.

Comment: Nothing like being able to *literally* wear a mod hat.

Comment: Thanks! I figured it out when I noticed the words 'MODERATOR HAT' [sic] in the DHL packing list. Still, I decided to post this question in the vile case somebody finds one of these on eBay in the future.

Comment: *Sell* a mod hat? inconceivable. (tho, my dad kept stealing it for a while till we got him his own hat)

Comment: Appointed mods also get it...

Comment: AMPAS used to have a rule that you couldn't sell an Oscar statuette. Do we need the same thing for moderator swag?

Comment: @Barmar: Such rules are only enforceable by either A) Punishes violators with consequences within the Stackoverflow system or B) Requiring swag recipients to sign a contract in advance of receiving swag.  AMPAS uses approach B.