# Winter Bash 2017 hatymology

Tags: discussion, winter-bash, winter-bash-2017

Inspired by a [long tradition](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/288803/295232), here's a list of the 'etymology' for the [Winter Bash 2017](https://winterbash2017.stackexchange.com/) hats. For pictures and a list of criteria, see [this topic](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/304340/295232) instead.

The list is a community wiki; feel free to edit it if you have more information about a hat. If you like to do some research, most hats have been featured in earlier editions, so you might be able to find more information in old Meta Stack Exchange questions.

Comment: That would be an option, but this is the way we've done it in the past. A reason to keep them separate is that these Winterbash lists tend to generate a lot of comments, and this way it will be easier to follow any 'discussion's.

Comment: Dear lord, man, your hat is gigantic. Pull/push the rotation control to resize!

Comment: I am considering changing the angle of my avatar just to wear my hats better ;)

Comment: The avatars are tiny, the hats a spot of colour, I can barely see people's faces (when it's not a pattern)  let alone their "hats" despite my setting the font size 125%. Avatars should be larger during Winter Bash, makes it more fun.

Comment: @Mari-LouA you could post that as a new [feature-request].

Comment: Naa... I don't have the time to make it into a full-blown FR with bells and whistles. If someone wants to make the same request they're free to do so. I'm not bothered :)

Comment: @MC10: "That would be an option, but this is the way we've done it in the past. A reason to keep them separate is that these Winterbash lists tend to generate a lot of comments, and this way it will be easier to follow any 'discussion's." -- [Glorfindel](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/295232/glorfindel) [Dec 13 at 13:16](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/304401/#comment989460_304401)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

#### Regular hats

<sub>let's keep them in alphabetical order, for easier search</sub>

- "And YOU Get A Hat!" is a reference to an [Oprah Winfrey meme](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/oprahs-you-get-a-car) based on an episode of her show where everyone in the audience was given a free car. The hat is designed like Oprah's hair.
- "Explorer" is a [Pith Helmet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pith_helmet), often worn by various jungle explorers. Explorers often visit less-trod ground, where it's unlikely to meet other people (who can upvote your answer).
- "Hero of Time" is a reference to [this Zelda character](https://zelda.gamepedia.com/Hero_of_Time).
- "Fascinator" is a reference to the hat worn by Princess Beatrice at the royal wedding in 2011. A "[fascinator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fascinator)" is a term for this type of hat that is largely decorative.
- "Fashionable" is a reference to [Iris Apfel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iris_Apfel) as a fashion icon.
- "Foot of the Rainbow" refers to one of the myths about the rainbow, that a pot of gold can be found at its end. The hat is obtained after getting a gold badge.
- "IDENTIFICATION DIVISION" is a reference to [Admiral Grace Hopper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grace_Hopper) and [COBOL](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_73/rzasb/iddiv.htm).
- "It's-a me!" is meant to resemble famous video game plumber, [Mario's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mario), hat and mustache. The name is a reference to one of his catchphrases.
- "Like Clockwork": a reference to [*A Clockwork Orange*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Clockwork_Orange_(film)). The hat is worn by the film's protagonist.
- "Milliner": [someone who makes women's hats](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/milliner).
- "Think!" is a [song by Aretha Franklin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Think_(Aretha_Franklin_song)) (the hat's original name, in 2013, was R-E-S-P-E-C-T, another song of hers).
- "This is fine" is [a meme](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/this-is-fine) and [an easter egg on the Stack Exchange chat server](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/75863/295232).
- "Waffles" are a [long running meme](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19480/295232) on the Stack Exchange network. And they are yummy.

#### Secret hats

> "Mother of Dragons" is a reference to the [Game of Thrones character Daenerys Targaryen](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/177517/44520) who has three dragon children.
>  The picture of "Ooh, Shiny!" is the [moderator hat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/299484/295232), given to ♦ moderators, whether they were appointed or elected, are active or retired. One of the things ♦ moderators do is closing and deleting posts. "Shiny" refers to the diamond.
>  "Red Hat With White Fur Trim" is a literal description of the [Christmas hat](https://www.google.com/search?q=christmas+hat); you got the hat by 'participating' on Christmas day.
>  The "Rep Cap" is an abbreviation of 'reputation cap', the informal name of the [daily reputation limit](/help/whats-reputation).
>  
>  "Row Of Many Candles" shows a [Menorah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menorah_(Hanukkah)), one of the items associated with Hanukkah; you got the hat by 'participating' on the last day of Hanukkah.
>  The "Some Kind Of Sun Thingy" shows a sun on it. You get that hat by participating on any site on December 21, the [Solstice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solstice). This is the day with shortest period of daylight in Northern Hemisphere and longest period of daylight in Southern Hemisphere.

Comment: I have a secret hat, but I'm not a mod.

Comment: But you earned it with actions moderators often do.

Comment: Fun fact "OOH SHINY!" is often the initial reactions new mods have. Shortly followed by existential dread.

Comment: I've got that secret hat and the original IRL as well. Do you, @axelout? I think it applies to all mods, active or retried.

Comment: Are there only 2 secret hats this year?

Comment: @JohnnyBones nope, see the linked Winter Bash 2017 Hats question.

Comment: Aaah, the secret of the shiny is revealed here https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/304345/1228

Comment: @alexolut I'm a mod, but I don't have that particular secret hat. An active regular user on a high traffic site is more likely to get it than a mod on a low traffic site.