# What is the "Ooh Shiny!" hat supposed to be?

Tags: support, winter-bash, winter-bash-2017, secret-hats

**Ooh, Shiny!**

[image: Ooh, Shiny!]

> Flag a question for closing, cast a close, delete or reopen vote on a question. You don't have to be the last vote, and hammers work.

(taken from [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/304345/360277))

And this is the Ethereum (Bitcoin's rival) logo:

[image]

Every time I see that hat, it remembers me of the Ethereum logo. Is this supposed to be an advertisement for the Ethereum Stack Exchange? If not, what is it supposed to be?

Comment: Also related: [What is this strange diamond logo on my Stack Exchange cap?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/299484/295232)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Nope.

This is the official SE moderator hat, which elected mods get sent automatically and appointed mods - like me - have to ask for one. But it looks like this:

[image: blue cap with SE diamond shaped logo on front]

It is the Stack Exchange logo -

[image: hamburger shaped SE logo divided into four parts]

cut into the shape of a diamond♦, the symbol used to mark a user as a moderator.

Answer (score 5):

No, it is not.

Stack Exchange delivered real hats with that logo for long time to elected moderators, long before Ethereum was even released.

In Stack Exchange case, that logo is the shape of a diamond, for its diamond moderators.